How to customize font size, wrap, and spacing in a forest plot generated by ggcoef_multinom?
I'm using the ggcoef_multinom so I can easily generate a forest plot. But I don't know how to customize the plot. I have looked at the various arguments that it takes and none of them handle customizing the font size, spacing, etc. I believe it uses ggplot2 but I don't know how to get the ggplot2 object back to customize it.
Please see the image. I want to reduce the font size of the variable levels (on the y-axis of the plot), wrap their labels, and if possible decrease the spacing between the plot and variable label showing on the left.

My code:
ggcoef_multinom(
  w_all_regression,
  exponentiate = TRUE,
  type = "table",
  plot_title = "Predictors for At Least 1 Dose of HPV Vaccination"
)


Hi, can someone answer please? I'm having another issue with the plot not showing up in my viewer unpredictably. #GGally
